When Canadian citizen residing abroad comes to visit Canada
My question may seem a bit silly, but when it comes to official matters, it's better to be sure. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find explicit information on travel.gc.ca, so maybe someone has some definite knowledge about this matter. A Canadian citizen, I've been living and working in Europe, and I haven't visited Canada in a few years now. I'm planning to visit Canada soon, and I looked at the border Declaration card, and I'm wondering if I'll have to declare myself as a Visitor or as a Resident?
From my understanding, because I'm a tax resident outside of Canada and my current residential address is also outside of Canada, despite being a Canadian citizen, I will be viewed as a Visitor by CBSA?

Yes, as long as you are indeed coming just for a visit (a few days, weeks or months) and not planning to return, you are a visitor.
It doesn't change much, though, the main difference is that you have much lower duty-free allowances.

But if later, down the road, I decide to return, will I have to declare myself as a Resident on the Declaration card? And if so, what will be my "Left Canada" date, the one since my most recent visit or the one when I left Canada a few years ago from now?

@sequence I don't know the specifics in Canada, but there are usually specific procedures when you actually move country, as you are generally entitled to much larger allowances for all the stuff you will be bringing to the country (either with you or through a moving company). No idea what you would put on that specific form, but that would probably be better asked on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com
